# SQL Server trigger that rounds values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I need to write a trigger that rounds a value whenever it is inserted/updated into a table

Comment: So what is the question? Have you tried anything? Post the issues/problems..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a getting started [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258254%28SQL.80%29.aspx) on how to use Triggers in SQL Server. Start working on it and let us know if you have any issues.

Comment: I ended up going with this as the answer because I did have to use a trigger, the reason being we're allowing users to use sql scripts to insert into the table and they're too lazy to round their own values (it's a price column), so we want to do it automatically.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @tt TABLE (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, value NUMERIC(10, 0) NOT NULL)

INSERT
INTO    @tt
VALUES  (1, 3.1415926)

SELECT  *
FROM    @tt
```

, without any triggers.